# Wordpress Cropped GIF has black background

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When i try to add a GIF image as product featured image in WooCommerce, it shows properly on single product page (as a transparent image), but on main shop page it shows with black background instead of being transparent.
This is the image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7oxu.gif (i am importing it via CSV)
And this is how it shows on single product:

[Single page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSgw5.png)

[and this is on main shop page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO4XP.png)

As you can see, it has black background on main shop page (i guess because it is cropped) and i was wondering can anybody help? I tried imagemagick plugin but it didnt work :(

I am using PHP 7 with latest WP and WooCommerce installed (running Storefront)

Comment: Save as PNG instead of GIF

Comment: Not because is cropped, is because of the format (.gif). The main shop page don't know what to do with the "transparent" layer. That's why it shows as black. Save it as jpg instead.

Comment: @HowardE sadly i cant, images are provided by 3rd party and then imported

Comment: @Syntax_Error If it was because of the format, then it wouldnt be displayed on single product page properly but it shows as it should. Only issue is on main store page where the image is resized

Comment: Can you show us a url to the site so we can see the code? or mor einfo because even Howard say is the format (changing the format from .gif to .png who can also read transparent layers).

Comment: You can't download the image and convert it to png? Really?